# How to change mouse buttons behaviour using winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to click my left mouse button, but get action like after clicked right mouse button and the same in the other side. So I would like to open folder clicking on it two Times my right mouse button.

When I try something like:

```
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return 1;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return 1;
```

My app doesn't answer ( I think I create while(1), because when I click WM_LBUTTONDOWN I send WM_RBUTTONDOWN, and next I send WM_LBUTTONDOWN, … ).

Comment: Why don't you just replace the calls to mouse_event, with a call to the code you want executed

Comment: You probably get into some kind of recursion. You click on the left button, which triggers `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, which calls `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,...` which triggers `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` which calls `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,...` which triggers `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` etc.

Comment: @newbie I want execute right button click in WM_LBUTTONDOWN, so I use mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0); Is something better?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah, but how Can I change my code to don't have recursion? :)

Comment: Do as suggested in the first comment. And BTW right double click for opening something is a very uncommon interaction, I've never seen this before. Don't invent strange interactions.

Comment: You already have a handler for the mouse event, you don't need another event. Just implement the code you want, under the switch case.. I also agree with @Jabberwocky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`SwapMouseButton()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-swapmousebutton) function:

> Reverses or restores the meaning of the left and right mouse buttons.
>
> ...
>
> Parameters
>
> `fSwap`
>
> Type: `BOOL`
>
> If this parameter is `TRUE`, **the left button generates right-button messages and the right button generates left-button messages**. If this parameter is `FALSE`, the buttons are restored to their original meanings.

Answer (score 0):

As Remy Lebeau provided, We can use [`SwapMouseButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-swapmousebutton) to exchange the meaning of the left and right mouse buttons.

And According to the document:

> Button swapping is provided as a convenience to people who use the mouse with their left hands. The `SwapMouseButton` function is usually called by Control Panel only. Although an application is free to call the function, the mouse is a shared resource and reversing the meaning of its buttons affects all applications.

So we need to call `SetMouseButton(FALSE)` before the end of the program to restore the mouse (if necessary).

Of course, if you need to modify the behavior in the middle of the program, but cannot determine whether the current mouse has been swapped in meaning, you can use the [`GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function to check whether the current mouse left and right buttons have been swapped.And nonzero if the meanings of the left and right mouse buttons are swapped; otherwise, 0.